# How exactly do I add an API endpoint to a jsp project I am working on?

Tags: java, api, jsp, endpoint

I am working on a OTP module of my project. I am working with API's for the 1st time. I found this website which provided me with API endpoint which is basically the url at which the service is available. Now I want to implement it in my jsp code. I am not sure How to do that.
This is the API endpoint given to me:

```
https://2factor.in/API/V1/API_KEY/SMS/+91PHONE_NUMBER/OTP_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addUserForm()
{
    //Collect input from html page
    var firstNameTxt = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var lastNameTxt = document.getElementById("lastName").value;

    var req = new REST.Request();
    req.setURI(REST.apiURL + "/rest/users");
    req.setMethod("POST");
    req.setEntity({firstName:firstNameTxt,lastName:lastNameTxt});
    req.execute(function(status, request, entity){
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "<h2><span style='color:red'>" + entity + " !!</span></h2>";
    });
}
```